# How can I functionally autofill props for a React Component?

Tags: reactjs

I have some public static `ColorPalette`:

```
// pseudo code
const ColorPalette = {
  input: {
    normal: "white",
    hover: "grey",
  },
  special: {
    normal: "green",
    hover: "darkgreen",
  },
}
export default ColorPalette;
```

I then have some button class which automatically fills in colors.  If the color is one which has a palette set up for it, it fills in with those.

```
// non functional code, for example of desired effect
class EasyButton extends React.Component<{color: string, hover: string}, any> {
  public static defaultProps = {
    color: ColorPalette.input.normal,
  }

  constructor(props) {
    if(props.color === ColorPalette.input.normal) {
      props.hover = ColorPalette.input.hover;
    } else if(props.color === ColorPalette.input.special) {
      props.hover = ColorPalette.special.hover;
    } else {
      props.hover = Darken(props.color);
    }
    super(props)
  }
}
```

The issue is that props can not be modified after super, and nothing can happen before super.  How can I autoset props functionally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't want to set your hover color in `constructor` because your component could have its color changed by its parent in a subsequent render. In that case, your hover color would remain unchanged.

Instead of modifying/adding props in the component, just calculate your `hover` color in `render`:

```
class EasyButton extends React.Component<{color: string, hover: string}, any> {
  public static defaultProps = {
    color: ColorPalette.input.normal,
  }

  getHoverColor = () => {
    if (this.props.color === ColorPalette.input.normal) {
      return ColorPalette.input.hover;
    } else if (this.props.color === ColorPalette.input.special) {
      return ColorPalette.special.hover;
    } else {
      return Darken(this.props.color);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const hover = this.getHoverColor()

    return // ...
  }
}
```

If you find that you're re-rendering regularly without the `color` prop changing, you could also put `hover` in `this.state` in `componentWillReceiveProps` when `color` changes.

```
class EasyButton extends React.Component<{color: string, hover: string}, any> {
  public static defaultProps = {
    color: ColorPalette.input.normal,
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.color !== this.props.color) {
      this.setState({ hover: this.getHoverColor() });
    }
  }

  getHoverColor = () => {
    if (this.props.color === ColorPalette.input.normal) {
      return ColorPalette.input.hover;
    } else if (this.props.color === ColorPalette.input.special) {
      return ColorPalette.special.hover;
    } else {
      return Darken(this.props.color);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: doing the work in render works, but it leads to the same logic being called for every new state.  I do see how this is more of the "react way" though so I'll consider this, within the realm of React, to be the correct answer.

Comment: @SephReed exactly. You want your components to *react* to state and prop changes. So, setting `hover` in your `constructor` goes against that principle. You do calculate `hover` multiple times (perhaps unnecessarily some of the time) by putting it in render, so that's why I included the approach with `componentWillReceiveProps`. That method will only ever re-calculate `hover` if it is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a decent answer while writing the question.  Make a static function and use it to create a new set of props based off the initial ones.

```
class EasyButton extends React.Component<{color: string, hover: string}, any> {
  public static defaultProps = {
    color: ColorPalette.input.normal,
  }

  public static autofillProps(props): the type of props {
    // based off props, make modifications, return new props
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(EasyButton.autofillProps(props));
  }
}
```

Hope this helps someone.